# HP ProLiant - Does ILO 2 Advanced offer additional SNMP or IPMI features?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, snmp, ipmi, ilo

We've got ML350 G5 servers with iLO 2 standard license.

Does upgrading to higher iLO license will unlock new SNMP or IPMI data registers?

If it will, which ones?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is licensing-related, and would therefore be much better directed to HP.

Comment: I think you need to be running iLO2 firmware rev 2.0 or later for IPMI support. You can get 30 day trials of the iLO advance licence pack to try out. I've never worked with an iLO without the advance pack, so can't say if that's what has given us SNMP support or not.

Comment: @MadHatter
HP asks for a valid contract to answer those kind of questions.
It's why I'm asking here, hopping someone has experienced it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does upgrading to higher iLO license will unlock new SNMP or IPMI data registers ?

No.

ILO2 Advanced gives you additional remote media and console functionality. It also provides power measurement/management and directory support.

What are you trying to achieve via the ILO2 and SNMP?

For that era server (2006-2009), I would not bother with investing any additional money into the hardware.